# Creating a folder structure

Tags: url-rewriting, user-roles, capabilities, members

My WP site has a members area which they pay to get access to.
I want that area to be a subfolder, so something like site.com/premium/nameofpage.

I am aware of url rewriting, htaccess etc. Is that the only way to get this working? Or is there a WP way to create a folder structure in the url?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is URL rewriting. If I understand correctly, what you want is to restrict access to certain pages, posts, categories, etc., based on the current user's role or capabilities:

> *"If logged in, do something. If not, do something else (like prompt to
>   login or register)."*

Modifying the output/behavior of a single page is not all that difficult. Just use the [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function to check the current user's status.

```
<?php 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        // Show your "logged in" user content here.
    } else{
        // Show your register/log in form here.
    }
?>
```

However, if what you want is TRULY a Member area, with multiple pages and sub-pages, I would consider using a plugin to accomplish this. In addition to the plugins offered in [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10167/25075), you might also want to check out [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/). Wordpress lists a few of these options as Resources on their [Roles and Capabilities page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Resources).

Simply create a page called "Premium" (for your specific case) and use one of these plugins (or something similar) to set restrictions for that page and every page beneath it. You could use a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) for that page to determine what functionality it includes.

Comment: The member management, controlling content etc is covered by this plugin (http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/) . I just want the user to feel like they are in an area of the site just for them hence wanting to create a bunch of pages all carrying out specific functionality under a folder called "premium".

Comment: I've not used the plugin before, but it looks like you could just create a page called "Premium" and use the Membership plugin to set restrictions for that page and every page beneath, it according to your needs. You could use a custom template for that page to determine what functionality it includes.